# unformatted output with wild card in Fortran

Tags: fortran, wildcard, fortran90

I've searched for a long time before I ask: I need to output a lot of unformatted files in Fortran to Ensight. I want to name them with geo.000000, geo.000001 ... geo.0001000. Here is how I deal with wild card:

```
character(54) :: filename, temp 
character(80) :: buffer
write(temp,'(i6.6)') step
filename = '/Users/jiecheng/Documents/SolidResults/solid.geo'//trim(temp) 
open(10,file=filename,form='UNFORMATTED')
open(10,file=filename,form='UNFORMATTED')
buffer = 'Fortran Binary'
write(10) buffer
buffer = 'Ensight Model Geometry File'
write(10) buffer

write(10,'(i10)') nn
write(10,'(i10)') node_id
do i=1,3
    write(10,'(E12.5)') sngl(coords1(i,:))
end do
```

Then I have

> Fortran runtime error: Format present for UNFORMATTED data transfer

Could anybody tell me how to solve this?

Comment: You should better re-write the line continuation within that string! As it is now, you have at least one whitespace in there! Better use `filename = '/Users/johnsmith' // &` and `'/Documents/...'`

Comment: I think the error message is not produced by the code you show us (there is no data transfer). Please post the correct line! I guess you have some `read` or `write` statement which has a format specified. This is not allowed for unformatted `stream` access. If you want to have formatted `stream` access (ASCII files), specify `FORM="FORMATTED"` in the `open` statement.

Comment: Alexander Vogt is right, the error meassage is produced by some read or write statement which you do not show.

Comment: Thank you Alex and Vladimir. I've posted my code again. I was trying to have unformatted files. And the name of the file is hopefully given with wild card. Actually I don't understand the meaning of "stream", "sequential" etc so I tried for many times. Please let me know the correct way.

Comment: It is still incomplete. Search for a read or write statement in the unformatted file, which contains a format, i.e. `(10,*)` or `(10,'(something)')` or `(10,100)` or something similar.

Comment: Edited again. Then I guess the problem is the write(10,'(i10)'). So does this mean in unformatted form, a number is stored in its original binary form and you cannot specify its format?

Comment: Correct.  In an unformatted file the numbers are stored in their machine-native representations and format statements to convert them to human-readable representations aren't appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a unit connected to a file for unformatted I/O it is illegal to specify a format as you do in

```
write(10,'(i10)') nn
```

The write of the value to the unformatted file is done in machine memory (binary) representation (some conversion may happen) and not as a human readable text. Therefore, the format specification does not have any sense.

Comment: You explained this well. Thank you.